# How to estimate a file size from header's sector start address?

Tags: linux, file, terminal

Suppose I have a deleted file in my unallocated space on a linux partition and i want to retrieve it.

Suppose I can get the start address of the file by examining the header.

Is there a way by which I can estimate the number of blocks to be analyzed hence (this depends on the size of the image.)

Comment: What if the file is fragmented?

Comment: What does it mean "examine the header"? Where it will come from?

Comment: @mvp say i delete a .jpg file. the header of a jpg file contains the characters ffd8ff... this certainly ensures that the sector head is the head of a image data file with . jpg extension.

Comment: @JimGarrison Say i have an image file which i have deleted recently.
Since it is not a very old unalocated space .. not much of it will be overwritten by other data. hence i'm assuming the file is continuous

Comment: @Pavan - Reading till EOF ? well i think that can only be done on files which are readable.. since this file has been deleted, there is no point "opening it" and then reading it. The issue simply relates to reading the sector information off an unallocated space where a file *was residing. and is residing but not interpreted by the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Linux/Unix does not support recovering deleted files - if it is deleted, it should be gone. This is also good for security - one user should not be able to recover data in a file that was deleted by another user by creating huge empty file spanning almost all free space.

Some filesystems even support so called secure delete - that is, they can automatically wipe file blocks on delete (but this is not common).

You can try to write a utility which will open whole partition that your filesystem is mounted on (say, `/dev/sda2`) as one huge file and will read it and scan for remnants of your original data, but if file was fragmented (which is highly likely), chances are very small that you will be able to recover much of the data in some usable form.

Having said all that, there are some utilities which are trying to be a bit smarter than simple scan and can try to be undelete your files on Linux, like [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/). It may work for you, but success is never guaranteed. Of course, you must be root to be able to use it.

And finally, if you want to be able to recover anything from that filesystem, you should unmount it right now, and take a backup of it using `dd` or pipe `dd` compressed through `gzip` to save space required.

Comment: A deleted sector where the file resides is declared as unallocated space until new data is written on it. The file is not actually gone.
Although this answer provides insight to the theory, i would please ask you to read the comments on the question that i have put to help me get a better answer ! 
Thanks